# Oracle SQL - Matching a phone format

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, select

I want to find datas that **do not** match the following pattern :

- any number of separator
- 2 numbers
- any number of separator
- 2 numbers
- any number of separator
- 2 numbers
- any number of separator
- 2 numbers
- any number of separator
- 2 numbers
- any number of separator

To do that, I use this query, but it does not seem to work :

```
select distinct regexp_replace(phonenumber, '[0-9]', '') 
from coord 
where REGEXP_LIKE(phonenumber, '^[ ./]{*}[0-9]{2}[ ./]{*}[0-9]{2}[ ./]{*}[0-9]{2}[ ./]{*}[0-9]{2}[ ./]{*}[0-9]{2}[ ./]{*}$')
```

What did I do wrong ?

Comment: What do you get as a result? `regexp_replace(phonenumber, '[0-9]', '')` seems suspicious to me. Do you get a list of empty strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want to search for the records that **DO** match your pattern, just replace your `{*}` with `*` :

```
SELECT DISTINCT regexp_replace(phonenumber, '[0-9]', '')
  FROM coord 
 WHERE regexp_like(phonenumber,
                   '^[ ./]*[0-9]{2}[ ./]*[0-9]{2}[ ./]*[0-9]{2}[ ./]*'
                   ||'[0-9]{2}[ ./]*[0-9]{2}[ ./]*$')
```

If you want to select the records that **DO NOT** match this pattern:

```
SELECT DISTINCT regexp_replace(phonenumber, '[0-9]', '')
  FROM coord 
 WHERE NOT regexp_like(phonenumber,
                       '^[ ./]*[0-9]{2}[ ./]*[0-9]{2}[ ./]*[0-9]{2}[ ./]*'
                       ||'[0-9]{2}[ ./]*[0-9]{2}[ ./]*$')
```